# It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I am getting the error "It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible"

also my Appium server gets killed autometically after this error in console.

Please help to resolve.

Comment: If you are using the desktop version of Appium Server, read through the console output.  The message you're reporting is quite common, but non-specific.  The details of your problem are almost certainly explained in more detail in the Appium Server logs on the desktop console.  Look for red dots (errors), and maybe yellow dots (warnings)

Answer (score 0):

The error may occurs from various reason. You need to check your appium server log to know the exact cause. Beside that you can verify following.

- Start your appium server in session-override option.
- Make sure your appium server is running.
- Make sure your are using correct url of appium server.
- Confirm your device is properly connecting to the laptop. You can verify it by using **adb devices** command (for android). Make sure it is showing **only one device**.
- Make sure your DesiredCapabilities are correct or all required desired capabilities are included.
- Try re-starting the appium server.

Comment: I get this error too but only when running iOS phones, Android phones work just fine.